# Lightbox using without bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, lightbox

Is there are way to use lightbox without bootstrap ? When I include bootstrap my styles get messed up. Even if I include it first or second, it still messes up my template. Or maybe you could suggest alternative script ?

Comment: What kind of lightbox do you use?

Comment: @GlebKemarsky ekko lightbox 3.3

Comment: That's http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/ Please add this information to your answer.

Comment: What does "messes up" mean? Ekko lightbox uses bootstrap modal, so it won't work without it.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/Simple-Gallery-Lightbox-Plugin-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-Ekko-Lightbox.html) write that

> Ekko Lightbox is a jQuery plugin which allows you to create a gallery lightbox using Bootstrap modal dialog component.

If this is true, then you need not all Bootstrap, but only [one component](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

Try to remove all the excess and use [a custom version of Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=4438bbc71d5a7759a9a78914dd3b02cd).

Answer (score -1):

Here is an alternative that works well with Bootstrap:

https://formstone.it/components/lightbox/